Computing $(1 + 1/n)^n$ accurately from $\log(1 + x)$ (exercise from Higham)
I am working on the following (paraphrased) exercise:
"Show how to compute $\log(1 + x)$ accurately for all $x > -1$, including for small $|x|$. Assume the log function is computed with relative error not exceeding $u$. Hence, by writing $(1 + 1/n)^n = \exp(n \log(1 + 1/n))$, show how to compute it accurately for large $n$."
The second part does not make sense to me. I think the answer to the first part is
y = 1 + x
if (y == 1) {
    f = x;
} else {
    f = log(y);
}

Under our model of floating point numbers, we have $y = (1 + x)(1 + \delta)$ for $|\delta| < u$. So if $y = 1$, then $x = -\frac{\delta}{1 + \delta}$. So $|x| < u$. This means that the relative error (using Taylor series)
$$\left|\frac{\log(1 + x) - x}{\log(1 + x)}\right| = \left|\frac{x^2 / 2 + O(x^3)}{x - x^2 / 2 + O(x^3)}\right| = O(x) \leq O(u).$$
So this should be accurate. However, that means we compute $(1 + 1/n)^n$ as $\exp(n(1/n)) = \exp(1) = e$. But we already know that $(1 + 1/n)^n$ converges to $e$, so what is the point behind evaluating $\log(1 + x)$ accurately? Or did I make a mistake in the error analysis?

What prevents you from using several terms of the Taylor series? By the alternating series test, the absolute value of the error term will be less than the absolute value of the first omitted term and will have the same sign as that term.

@Gary That is essentially what I do for small $x$. For $x > 1$ the first omitted term may be large though.

But $x=1/n$ is small, so you are fine.
